# Map an Object Property in a POJO given an ID from a JSON

Tags: spring, jpa, jackson

First of all, sorry, I cannot explain myself in any better way.

I am programming an example API,  I have a POJO (with JPA) called Movie, so in my controller, I want to give it a JSON to insert a Movie.

Movie has a `@ManyToOne(optional = false)` property, relating another POJO called `Genre` (`idGenre`, `Name`)

I want to give in a JSON not an object with every property but an id, so:

**CONTROLLER**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendMovie", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void setMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie) {
    mRepo.save(movie);
}
```

**Movie**

```
@Entity
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_MOVIE", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long idMovie;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "SYNOPSIS")
    private String synopsis;

    @Column(name = "POSTER")
    private String poster;

    @Column(name = "DIRECTOR")
    private String director;

    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "idGenre")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_GENRE", referencedColumnName = "ID_GENRE")
    private Genre genre;
```

**JSON I want to use**

```
{
  "name": "MATRIX",
  "idGenre": 3,
  "synopsis": "NEO DOING THINGS",
  "poster": "matrix.jpg",
  "director": "WACHOWSKIS"
 }
```

Is there possibility to achieve that?

Comment: Sure. Design a class that matches with the JSON you want to send and receive, different from the Movie class, Let's call it a MovieCreationCommand. When you receive a MovieCreationCommand in your controller, create a Movie, initializing all its properties by getting them out of the command, and getting the genre from the database using the genre ID found in the command, then insert that movie.

Answer (score 2):

You did put the `JsonIdentity...` annotations at the wrong place.

You need to put these annotations on your `@Genre` class:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "idGenre")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
public class Genre {
    @Id
    @Column(...)
    private Long idGenre;

    //....
}
```

and remove these annotations from the property `Genre genre` in your `Movie` class.
You also need to tell Jackson with `@JsonProperty("idGenre")` that you want this property
serialized with name `"idGenre"`.

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_GENRE", referencedColumnName = "ID_GENRE")
@JsonProperty("idGenre")
private Genre genre;
```

Then the JSON output will be something like this:

```
{
  "name": "MATRIX",
  "synopsis": "NEO DOING THINGS",
  "poster": "matrix.jpg",
  "director": "WACHOWSKIS",
  "idGenre": 3
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Thomas, but I want to give that JSON as input to add a new movie into the DB, and i get a JSON parse error when using this

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.UnresolvedForwardReference: Unresolved forward references for:`